# Why the need to say « aurais épousé » instead of « épouserais » here?

Tags: temps-grammatical

> Si tu **étais née** princesse, alors c’est toi qui **aurais épousé** le prince demain.
>
> {instead of}: Si tu **étais née** princesse, alors c’est toi qui **épouserais** le prince demain.

I cannot pinpoint why the past conditional is considered appropriate here. It might just be that I find the *future*-denoting word « demain » conflicting with the *past* conditional, even though I should know better.

Comment: Is this sentence from a book? If yes when was it published?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Hi. This is a spoken sentence of someone who has a habit of speaking in a rather formal register.

Comment: Ok. That's what I suspected. In a *conte* I would expect *Si tu avais été née*, but nowadays nobody would use plus-que-parfait here, it sounds almost as literary as using *passé simple* in speech.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ici nous sommes en présence d'une phrase exprimant un irréel avec une proposition conditionnelle introduite par *si* avec un verbe à l'imparfait (*si tu étais née*). La règle de base est de mettre la principale au conditionnel :

> Si tu étais née princesse, alors c’est toi qui épouserais le prince demain.

Si la condition avait été exprimée avec un plus-que-parfait cette même règle de base aurait été de mettre la principale au conditionnel passé :

> Si tu avais été née princesse, alors c’est toi qui aurais épousé le prince demain.

Voir par exemple [sur Bonjour de France](http://www.bonjourdefrance.com/exercices/contenu/20/grammaire/583.html) cette règle de base des concordance des temps dans les subordonnées de condition introduites par *si*.

Ceci dit l'emploi du conditionnel passé ne me choque pas dans la phrase :

> Si tu étais née princesse, alors c’est toi qui aurais épousé le prince demain.

Pourquoi ? J'émets deux hypothèses qui peuvent coexister.

1. *êtais née* est un imparfait composé de deux termes, imparfait de l'auxiliaire *être* suivi d'un *participe passé / adjectif*. De par sa structure on pourrait inconsciemment l’assimiler à un plus-que parfait.
2. Le conditionnel passé confère à l'action un aspect plus achevé, la rend encore plus inéluctable.

La *Grammaire Larousse du français contemporain* dit que :

> À condition que l'on tienne compte d'une règle essentielle selon laquelle la conjonction *si* n'est jamais suivie elle-même du futur de l'indicatif ou du conditionnel, beaucoup de substitutions sont possibles dans [les structures de concordances décrites ci-dessus].

Bien entendu si on considère que dans ces phrases nous sommes en présence du verbe *naître* et non pas de *être né*, alors la première phrase de la question (plus-que-parfait → conditionnel) passé est strictement conforme à la règle de base.

Comment: Hi. I wonder if the tense "si tu **étais née**" isn't the **plus-que-parfait**, with the English equivalent being "if you **had been** born"?
 http://conjugaison.lemonde.fr/conjugaison/search?verb=n%C3%A9e+

Comment: To me it is an *imparfait* in that sentence, but I know it is debatable and I might get lots of comments. If you consider it is *plus-que-parfait* then the 1st sentence you give follows the basic rule.

Comment: @Laure: Je suis d'accord sur le fait que c'est un imparfait, c'est bien une construction avec attribut. Je pense par contre qu'il ne faut pas confondre ça avec une construction au passif puisque *naitre* n'est pas transitif.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez oui, t'as raison... ce n'est pas passif (enfin pas au sens grammatical !) j'corrige.

Answer (score 0):

*épouserais* est au présent du conditionnel, *aurais épousé* est un conditionnel passé. Le conditionnel passé exprime ici le regret de quelque chose qui est **définitivement** impossible. C'est une conditionnel qui appartient au passé. Peut-être un peu à la manière de "if I were a rich man" ?
Avec le conditionnel présent, il peut encore y avoir une chance d'épouser ce prince. Il suffirait d'ajouter trois points de suspension à la fin de la 2ème phrase pour qu'on imagine un stratagème permettant de faire croire qu'elle née princesse. Avec la 1ère phrase, je ne pense pas. On reste dans le regret, voir une sorte de reproche.